# is there a faster way to receive input with python? (USACO)

Tags: python

I'm new to competitive coding and was doing a practice USACO question with an input structure like this:

```
5 3
1
6
4
3
1
```

the first number is the number of numbers below it, and the second number next to it would be needed for something else in the problem

heres the code I wrote to try to recieve the input

```
a = list(input())
n = int(a[0])
k = int(a[2])

diamonds = []

for x in range(n):
  this = int(input())
  diamonds.append(this)
```

the first two numbers I put in a list, converted to int, then assigned them to two variables, I then created an array with a for loop to receive the list of numbers below, converting them to int first

although it works, I feel like this is inefficent and is wasting time, is there another, faster way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you feel this is inefficient or wasting time? Did you want to allow multiple numbers to be input on the same line?

Comment: You probably want `n, k = map(int, input().split())`. What  you have isn't particularly inefficient, but it seems to assume a very specific input format (single-digit numbers separated by exactly one character, with no leading or trailing non-digit characters).